# what type of attack does LOIC do?

Tags: network, denial-of-service, ddos

I have used LOIC (Low Orbit Ion Cannon) earlier .
Today i was reading on wikipedia that there are many types of dos attacks , namely SYN attacks , HTTP flooding ,UDP flooding ,etc and two questions striked my mind .

1)I want to know which type of attack can LOIC do ?

2)Can anyone list the examples of dos attacks in different osi layers ?

Comment: "Denial of Service" is a broad category of attack. Trying to list them all is not going to be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for comment . Can you tell me html and syn flooding are which level attacks ?

Comment: If you read any of the documentation on LOID, it tells you this. This question is not on topic here - it is not a security question.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia TCP and UDP flood. 
The list of attacks is too long to name all of them. I think it will be good exercises for you to do it alone. It's easy for example TCP flood will operate on layer 4 because UDP is operating on this layer(Transport layer).

Comment: According to the screenshot, you can enter a URL which suggests it can also do HTTP flooding.

Comment: What about syn flooding and html flooding?

Comment: @hellruler What do you mean "HTML flooding"? That's not a term I'm familiar with (or can find anywhere online).